# any method to estimate determinant of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm writing a kernel on GPU to compute determinant for my image processing app. The matrices are binary (only have value $[0,1]$), sparse, and have size $32\times32$.
Is there any method for estimating determinants quickly? The error can be high, $10$%, even $20$%.

Some relevant discussions & papers:

- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180604/are-bounds-known-for-the-maximum-determinant-of-a-0-1-matrix-of-specified-size?rq=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135703/determinant-of-sparse-matrix
- https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0024379518302593

Comment: Is the determinant to be computed mod 2? Or is this a matrix of integers, all of which just happen to be $0$ or $1$, and you want the integer-valued determinant?

Comment: @JohnHughes yes, second case

Comment: So would I, but ... it seemed worth asking. And "20% error" is a bit ambiguous as well. Does it have to get the right answer 80% of the time? Or if the matrix is singuler, so that the det is zero, must it always get it exactly right?

Comment: I imagine they want the bound on the error of the approximation to be at most 20%

Comment: For a singular matrix, where the true determinant is $0$, what does a 20% error mean? 20% of the maximum possible determinant of all 0/1 matrices? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardsMaximumDeterminantProblem.html suggests a bound on that number is about $10^{14}$, which seems large.

Comment: If you want the exact value, Gaussian elimination, followed by taking the determinant (it's an $O(n^2)$ algorithm) is the only thing I can think of at the moment.

Comment: @JohnHughes currently I have the implementation of LU decomposition and gauss elimination, they give the exact result but quite slow. I tried to modify the result up and down ~10% and the final outcome was still acceptable. So now I'm looking for a faster way to estimate it

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135703/determinant-of-sparse-matrix (and links therein)

Comment: Do you know the sparsity pattern in advance? Or are all of the entries of the matrix unknown?

Comment: The fact that the dimension is a power of $2$ should surely be taken into account.

Comment: Years ago, I wrote some code to compute the permanent of a $0-1$ matrix.  I did it by expansion by minors, and I recall that I got a large speedup simply by never doing any multiplication.  I just skipped over the $0$s and added the minors corresponding to the $1$s.  Of course, for determinants, you may have to subtract.  I vaguely recall that I experimented with a greedy algorithm:  always expand along the row or column with the fewest $1$s.  I don't remember how that work out though.   Of course, determinants are faster to compute than permanents, so I don't know if these ideas are useful.

Comment: " I tried to modify the result up and down ~10% and..."  So what exactly did you do when you modified an exact answer of $0$ up by 10%? Did it remain zero? Must our proposed solutions compute zero-determinants exactly?

Comment: it was still 0 when the correct answer is 0. I'd love to know any possible approach.

Comment: Let us consider a concrete case. If in average, one digit among ten is a "1", a quick simulation has given me $\det(A)=0$ in about 95% cases. For a such sparsity degree, an important cause of nullity for the determinant is to have a column or a line to be entirely $0$. Therefore, a first "sanity check" is 
- to sum all rows : if one of these sums is 0, exit with $\det(A)=0$
- otherwise, sum all columns : if one of these sums is 0, the same (exit with $\det(A)=0$)

Comment: @JeanMarie I do have that check. The matrices are pure random so there're avg 32*32/2 1's

Comment: I had a fundamental misunderstanding : I understand now that the sparsity you are mentionning is in the computional science meaning the way the matrix is represented, not the "s$\color{red}{p}$arcity"  as "s$\color{red}{c}$arcity" of non-zero elements as it is defined in linear algebra !

Comment: For further documentation use keywords "binary matrices" or "(0-1) matrices" (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/01-Matrix.html)

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks for your help. Really appreciate that! I just found this paper a couple hours ago: "Determinant Computation on the GPU using the
Condensation Method", link: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/944e/5d5803cc01d83440df8129994a2dc7515a6c.pdf
my quick implementation is slightly faster than LU decomposition & gauss elimination. The hard part is handling under/overflow